# Xcode debugger: show __m256i as int32_t[8] instead of int64_t[4]?

Tags: c++, xcode9, lldb, intrinsics

I'm using Xcode to debug a C++ program with SIMD intrinsics. Xcode's watch window displays the `__m256i` type as an aggregate of 4 64-bit ints by default. However, I'm using them as primarily for 32-bit integers, and would like to see them as 8 32-bit ints instead. For an individual variable, I can create a new watch expression like `*((uint32_t(*)[8])(&varName))`, and result is good enough. However, having to do this manually for every single stack variable would be impractically tedious and cumbersome.

I've tried editing the summary format string (`right click -> "Edit Summary Format..."`) for the type, which seems like it ought to do the trick, but couldn't find good documentation online for how these format strings are supposed to be written for C++, and wasn't able to figure it out by trial and error.

Is there a format string that would give the result I'm looking for? Or if not, is there some other way to change how the type is displayed by default?